# Querying the status of children in Unix shell

Tags: c, unix

I'm trying to implement a Unix shell for a class project and I'm running into some issues. Namely this method

```
void checkStatus()
{
printf("checking status\n");
job_t* checkStart = first_job;
while(checkStart != NULL)
{
    process_t* processStart = checkStart->first_process;
    while(processStart != NULL)
    {
        int status;
        pid_t test = waitpid(processStart->pid, &status, WUNTRACED | WNOHANG);
        printf("%d\n", processStart->pid);
        printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));
        printf("%d\n", status);
        printf("%d\n", test);

        if(WIFEXITED(status))
        {
            printf("exited\n");
        }
        if(WIFSTOPPED(status))
        {
            printf("stopped\n");
        }
        processStart = processStart->next;
    }
    checkStart = checkStart->next;
}
}
```

is supposed to query the status of all of the processes that are running or have been run so that the process structs can be updated (I need to be able to print out the status of each one). When I try to test this by running a foreground process and using ctrl+z to pause it, it always returns as exited. Also if I use ctrl+c to stop it it returns an error saying no child processes are available but also returns exited. Am I querying the statuses wrong? Also this is supposed to be implemented without using signals so I can't go that route.

Thanks!

Comment: How are you running a foreground process as the child process?

Comment: Fork is being used to create every process, the foreground process runs and control is transferred back to the shell afterwards. Wouldn't using fork in the shell make that new copy a child of the original?

Comment: Inside of the forked process, are you using exec() or system()?

Comment: I'm using exec. I'm pretty sure none of the files have the setuid bit set if that's what you're alluding to.

Comment: How are you stopping the child without stopping the parent?

Comment: BTW: The status is only valid if waitpid returns a value greater than zero.

Comment: In the case of a foreground job the child exits and then control is returned to the parent. That is also done with a wait call which works fine. (i.e. the parent calls wait on the foreground child and waits until it is done). The issues really is with querying background jobs, I'm just using the foreground jobs for testing purposes.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue, but when I hit Ctrl-Z, the parent process stops as well.

Comment: That's odd, if the child is in the foreground ctrl+z should only affect that I would think. Is there anything wrong with the semantics of the method that you can see? If I know that's being done right then I can look for issues in other areas.

Comment: The only thing I see is that WIFEXITED(status) and WIFSTOPPED(status) are being called even when test is zero, but the status is garbage in that case.

Comment: Are you creating a new process group for your child processes?

Comment: Yes, each process struct (or group in case of pipes) is inside a job struct with a process group id.

Comment: I did a test where I created the child process, put the child process in its own process group, and made the new process group be the foreground process group.  When I stopped the child process using ctrl-z, the waitpid() in the parent process returned the child process id and WIFSTOPPED(status) was true, but WIFEXITED(status) was false.  So I'm not able to reproduce the issue.  Maybe you could post a complete minimal example of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, did you specifically call a function to set the new process group to be in the foreground? If so what was it? I wonder if that my be my problem.

Comment: In the parent process, I have `tcsetpgrp(0,child_pid);` just after the fork.

Comment: Interesting, I may just try that then. Thanks again for all of your time.